# Getting a p value from a t statistic

Tags: r

I'm comparing a long list of observations for two groups, and I have the t statistic and the degrees of freedom for each observation, but I don't actually have the original data. Despite that, I would like to get the p value associated with the t statistic. I know this is possible, but I can't figure out how to get R to report back a p value. Any advice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [task view on Distributions](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Distributions.html) should be your first port of call to answer questions like this

To quote

> For most of the classical distributions, base R provides probability
>   distribution functions (p), density functions (d), quantile functions
>   (q), and random number generation (r). Beyond this basic
>   functionality, many CRAN packages provide additional useful
>   distributions. In particular, multivariate distributions as well as
>   copulas are available in contributed packages.

You are after the `t` distribution, and a value from the probability distribution function, so the function you are after is `pt`

```
pt(q, df)
```

where `q` is your `quantile`, in this case your observed test statistic, and `df` the degrees of freedom

I'm not sure what you mean by `the degrees of freedom for *each* observation`, I presume you mean you know the number of observations in each group.

So, if you have assumed within group variances were equal, then the degrees of freedom would be `n1+n2 - 2`, otherwise you would need to account for the unequal variances and obtain an approximate degrees of freedom ([Welch-Satterthwaite modification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t_test))